# How should i manage Sessions and Transactions in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a function that has some nested if statements and a query in each of the if statements ,how should i manage transaction and session calls.I know that i should bind each call with seperate transaction .

```
Session session=null;
Transaction tx=null;
if(!list.isEmpty()){
    session=factory.openSession();
    tx=session.beginTransaction();
    session.createQuery(" update Tbluser set loggedStatus='9'").executeUpdate();
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
    if(list.get(1)=="N")
    {
        ///some query
    }
}
```

should i have not closed the session just yet or should i create a new Session object for the new query that i have? or what else should be the correct approach?

Comment: does something not work?  A good way to learn is to experiment by yourself.

Comment: everything works fine but performance wise what should be correct approach!

Comment: use a DB Connection Pool class

Comment: @ScaryWombat yes i can use connection pool but to be on the safe side,what should be an exact recommended approach?

Answer (score 0):

If all the operations in the if blocks are related and atomic, you should consider opening one session and transaction before the first if block and commit/close after the last if block.

If each operations is separate, then you can open one session before the first if and enclose each if in a new transaction.